# Highlight duplicate value in a comma based string

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

If I have values in cell c3= 2,4,6,8,12,14,18,23,35,78,101,38,30,205,2,101
In This two values are duplicate which is { 2,101 } 
I want notification as and when enter any value twice, three-time , forth time, etc in that cell i should come to know which value is repeated. Duplicate values can be shown in adjacent cell D3,
[image: example sheet here]

Comment: I believe this isn't possible as you type. If you need interruption while you type use the TextBox's Change event. In that case the issue of having more than one duplicate wouldn't arise. In a worksheet cell you have to wait with the check until the user finishes typing in that cell. If this is what you want (meaning, you don't want to use a textbox) I would recommend to notify only the first duplicate, such permitting multiple notifications in sequence if there are more than one duplications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Test_CheckDups_UDF()
With Range("A1")
    .Value = "2,4,6,8,12,14,18,23,35,78,101,38,30,205,2,101"
    .Offset(, 1).Value = CheckDups(.Value)
End With
End Sub

Function CheckDups(s As String) As String
Dim a, dic As Object, i As Long

Set dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
a = Split(s, ",")

For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    If dic.Exists(a(i)) = True Then CheckDups = CheckDups & IIf(CheckDups = Empty, "", ",") & a(i) Else dic.Add a(i), 1
Next i
End Function
```

Here's a code that will highlight the duplicates within the same cell. Tweak it so as to suit your needs

```
Sub Highlight_Duplicates_Within_Cell()
Dim s, sp, k, c As Range, t As String, f As Boolean, n As Long

For Each c In Range("C3:C13")
    c.Font.Color = vbBlack

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        sp = Split(c.Value, ",")
        For Each s In sp
            If Not .Exists(s) Then .Add s, 1 Else .Item(s) = .Item(s) + 1
        Next s

        For Each k In .Keys
            t = "," & k & ","
            f = False
            n = InStr(1, "," & c.Value & ",", t, vbTextCompare)
            Do While n And .Item(k) > 1
                If f Then
                    c.Characters(n, Len(t) - 2).Font.Color = vbRed
                End If
                n = InStr(n + Len(k), "," & c.Value & ",", t, vbTextCompare)
                f = True
            Loop
        Next k
    End With
Next c
End Sub
```

Try this version too using Regex

```
Sub Highlight_Duplicates2()
Dim mtch As Object, mtch2 As Object, m As Object, mm As Object, c As Range, txt As String, i As Long

For Each c In Range("C3:C13")
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        txt = c.Value
        .Pattern = " *(\w+)"
        Set mtch = .Execute(txt)

        For Each m In mtch
            .Pattern = "\b" & m.submatches(0) & "\b"
            Set mtch2 = .Execute(txt)

            If mtch2.Count > 1 Then
                For i = 1 To .Execute(txt).Count - 1
                    Set mm = mtch2(i)
                    With c.Characters(mm.firstindex + 1, mm.length).Font
                        .Color = vbRed: .Bold = True
                    End With
                    Mid$(txt, mm.firstindex + 1, mm.length) = Space(mm.length)
                Next i
            End If
        Next m
    End With
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: @Gary's Student I am your student and I am learning a lot from you.

Comment: I have added loop to suit your needs.

Comment: It's working on my workbook. What's c.address in the immediate window which the error occurs at? Are the data in the column C constants or a result of a formula?

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH, it worked finally after inserting a shape and assigning macro named "Highligh_duplicates within the cell" . is this right way isn't it

Comment: That's OK. I have added new code using regex. Hope this helps you too.

Comment: @YasserKhalil sir can you please help me that how can I write the cell values in ascending or descending order Ex-  IF  A1=2,4,6,8,12,14,18,23,35,78,101,38,30,205,2,101,G1,B1,M1,H1 and I want to arrange in smallest to largest in  adjacent cell B1 my result should be =2,2,6,8,12,18,23,30,35,78,101,101,205,B1,G1,H1,M1

Comment: This is a different question. I suggest posting a new question better.

Answer (score 2):

This does not meet your request of trapping duplicates while typing. However to process a comma-separated string (*once entered*) consider the following user defined function:

```
Public Function duplist(s As String) As String
    Dim s2 As String, arr
    Dim kount As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    arr = Split(s, ",")

    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        kount = 0
        v = arr(i)
        For j = 0 To i
            If v = arr(j) Then kount = kount + 1
        Next j
        If kount = 2 Then s2 = s2 & "," & v
    Next i
    duplist = Mid(s2, 2)
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: If highlights of duplicate values may be possible in same cell  then it will be so helpful

Comment: @MilanKumar  I don't know how to do that.